# Convert date to varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert Date to varchar to the following format. Please help with the syntax.

```
SELECT CONVERT (CAST('10-11-2015' AS Date) VARCHAR)
```

I need the following output.

```
Sunday, October 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DATENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function:

```
DECLARE @Date   DATETIME
SELECT  @Date   = '2015-10-11'

SELECT  DATENAME(dw, @Date) + ', ' + 
        DATENAME(mm, @Date) + ' '  + 
        DATENAME(dd, @Date)
```